# BigQuery: Export to GCS option disappeared from BigQuery UI

Tags: google-bigquery

The option to export to a GCS bucket has disappeared from the BigQuery UI and was replaced with "Export to Google Drive". It's a feature I used a lot for large results and using the export to Drive is not useful at all. It takes very long and I can't work the same way with the file in Drive than I would in GCS. Is there any way I can still export to GCS from BigQuery UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "workaround" for BigQuery UI is to save result as a table (or just have destination table set for query) and after result is available in the table - just use "Export to GCS" option which is "still" available in both Classic and New BQ UI